# Oracle 19c: All the system views gone

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle 19c on linux . I have a database and connect using

sqlplus / as sysdba

after connect successfully . I found nearly all the system views are gone like dba_users,dba_objects.......

and all throw the error

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

[image]

Comment: So what did you do before this point? Is it a fresh install?

Comment: i will need to run @?/rdbms/admin/catalog.sql and @?/rdbms/admin/catproc.sql